# MAME in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mame

I've searched this and can only find older threads and for older versions of Linux.

I want to install MAME (arcade emulator) on Ubuntu 16.04. Anyone that has actually got MAME working on Ubuntu 16.04 please let me know the exact process. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You can get very clear instructions at http://sdlmame.wallyweek.org/repository/ on how to install MAME via an unofficial PPA, which I copy verbatim here because there isn't anything to add:

Open a terminal window (commands may be typed directly or pasted into it) and:

1. Remove old sdlmame repositories (if any):

   ```
   sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sdlmame4ubuntu.*
   ```
2. Add the main repository for unofficial builds:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c.falco/mame
   ```
3. (optionally) add the repository for "u"(nstable) builds:

   **(Skip this step to stick with main, stable, not-"u" releases!)**

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c.falco/umame
   ```
4. Now update the information on your box:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Finally install the package from the repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mame
   ```

Comment: So. I got MAME installed (it installed 0.174). But I can't get any ROMs (Games) to work. Any ideas what I should try and do? Again - Internet advice is for older versions of both Ubuntu and MAME.

Answer (score 2):

I came across [this video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/xlYHnrqMZGs) which shows additional configuration steps. Not tested by myself so take with a grain of salt.
In summary:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c.falco/mame
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mame
```

Then edit the configuration file to set your default rompath

```
gedit ~/.mame/mame.ini
```

And change the rompath line if necessary. The video shows it as

```
rompath     $HOME/mame/roms;/usr/local/share/games/mame/roms
```

**Don't** follow the video's advice to use `sudo nautilus` - that's a very bad idea. If you *really* need to open nautilus as root (which should **not** often be the case, do

```
sudo -i
nautilus <some directory> &
```

and when done, remember to type

```
exit
```

in the terminal to drop privileges